# MySQL Error 1261 - How to import TSV file with blank cell values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to import multiple large TSV files into a MySQL database and I am receiving the following error:

```
Error Code: 1261. Row 14 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

Row 14 has a column which is blank (holds no value). How can I import these TSV files such that blanks in the TSV file are imported as blanks in the DB table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:/infile.tsv'
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(`name`,`user`);
```

I have only included name and user fields here but there are another 45 fields in the test table.

Comment: Is it really a 'blank' value as you say, or are there too few columns? A blank is still a value, but if you don't have enough 'commas' this might be real problem

Comment: Hi @Evert they are blanks. In the problematic row, the column that is causing an issue has a tab no value proceeded by another tab

Comment: Ah weird, I would have expected that to be treated as an empty string.